# How do you bypass or skip the intro message when starting screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

When I start `screen`, I get a message giving the version, copyright, and bug-reporting email address.  I don't want to see this every time I start `screen`.  Searching the man page didn't seem to result in a solution, and I am hoping that the experts here know a way to bypass this info page.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There's a setting for that:

```
# Don't display the copyright page
  startup_message off           # default: on
```

You can set that system-wide (in `/etc/screenrc`) or only for your account (in `~/.screenrc`).  Shortcut commands:

```
# Skipping the startup message for your account.
echo 'startup_message off' >> ~/.screenrc

# Skipping the startup message for all accounts.
sudo bash -c "echo 'startup_message off' >> /etc/screenrc"
```

Comment: For future me: `echo 'startup_message off' >> ~/.screenrc`

Comment: Or help your brothers on the server as well: `sudo bash -c "echo 'startup_message off' >> /etc/screenrc"` (turns it off for all users rather than for yourself only)

Comment: @Luc That depends; your brothers and sisters might find the welcome page useful, so it might not necessarily be a great idea to edit it system-wide. "It depends".

Comment: BTW, that setting is in the GNU Screen User Reference Manual, in the Command Summary section (https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Command-Summary)

Answer (score 4):

```
screen -q
```

also works for me, if you don't want to touch files.

Comment: I think this answer is better than the accepted one.

Comment: -q says: Suppress printing of error messages. In combination with -ls the exit value is as follows: 9 indicates a directory without sessions. 10  indicates
            a  directory  with running but not attachable sessions. 11 (or more) indicates 1 (or more) usable sessions.  In combination with -r the exit value
            is as follows: 10 indicates that there is no session to resume. 12 (or more) indicates that there are 2 (or  more)  sessions  to  resume  and  you
            should specify which one to choose.  In all other cases -q has no effect.